# How to sort by an element inside a deep object in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

I have this mapping:

```
{
    "foos": {
        "mappings": {
            "foo": {
                "dynamic": "false",
                "properties": {
                    "some_id": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "language": {
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    "locations": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "name": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "term_vector": "yes",
                        "analyzer": "name_analyzer"
                    },
                    "popularity": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "some_deep_count": {
                        "type": "object"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

one example entry is the following:

```
                 {
                    "name": "Some nice name",
                    "some_id": 1,
                    "id": 4378,
                    "popularity": 525,
                    "some_deep_count": {
                        "0": {
                            "32026": 344,
                            "55625": 458,
                            "29": 1077,
                            "55531": 1081,
                            ...
                        },
                        "1": {
                            "32026": 57,
                            "55625": 60,
                            "29": 88,
                            ...
                        }
                    },
                    "locations": [
                        32026,
                        55625,
                        ...
                    ],
                    "language": [
                        "es",
                        "en"
                    ]
                }
```

where the `some_deep_count` field can contain only the "0" and "1" keys, which inside of them can contain a very long list of id => value (dynamic, not configurable in advance)

This works very well when filtering:

```
"_source": [
        "id",
        "some_deep_count.*.55529"
    ],
```

but I don't understand how to sort by any deep object. I need a deep sum, like the following expression indicates:

```
...
{
    "sort": {
        "_script": {
            "type": "number",
            "script": {
                "lang": "painless",
                "source": "def deep0 = 0; def deep1 = 0; if(doc.containsKey('some_deep_count.0.55529')) { deep0 = doc['some_deep_count.0.55529'] } if(doc.containsKey('some_deep_count.1.55529')) { deep1 = doc['some_deep_count.1.55529'] } return deep0 + deep1"
            },
            "order": "desc"
        }
    }
}
```

which unfortunately always returns `0` in the sorting field, since `doc.containsKey('some_deep_count.0.55529')` results always being empty. Also `doc.containsKey('some_deep_count')` does.

Interestingly enough, `doc.containsKey('some_id')` would work, and I really can't understand why

EDIT

In response to Val's proposal, I'm attaching a full request / response

Request:

```
{
  "sort": {
  "_script": {
    "type": "number",
    "script": {
      "lang": "painless",
      "source": "def ps0 = 0; if(doc.containsKey('some_deep_count.0.55529')) { ps0 = doc['some_deep_count.0.55529'].value; }  return ps0 "
    },
    "order": "desc"
  }
},
  "_source": [
      "id",
      "some_deep_count.0.55529"
  ],
  "size": 1
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "took": 4,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 2121,
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "foos",
                "_type": "foo",
                "_id": "5890",
                "_score": null,
                "_source": {
                    "some_deep_count": {
                        "0": {
                            "55529": 228
                        }
                    },
                    "id": 5890
                },
                "sort": [
                    0.0
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The issue is probably to be found in the condition. In fact I get `"sort":[0.0]` even when the sorting is as simple as `"def ps0 = 0; if(doc.containsKey('some_deep_count')) { ps0 = 99999; }  return ps0 "`, revealing that the clause `doc.containsKey('some_deep_count')` might have some problem

EDIT2

The index got with `curl -XGET localhost:9200/foos` looks like the following:

```
{
  "foos": {
      "aliases": {},
      "mappings": {
          "foo": {
              "dynamic": "false",
              "properties": {
                  "some_id": {
                      "type": "integer"
                  },
                  "language": {
                      "type": "text"
                  },
                  "locations": {
                      "type": "integer"
                  },
                  "name": {
                      "type": "text",
                      "term_vector": "yes",
                      "analyzer": "name_analyzer"
                  },
                  "popularity": {
                      "type": "integer"
                  },
                  "some_deep_count": {
                      "type": "object"
                  }
              }
          }
      },
      "settings": {
          "index": {
              "number_of_shards": "5",
              "provided_name": "foos",
              "creation_date": "1576168104248",
              "analysis": {
                  "analyzer": {
                      "name_analyzer": {
                          "filter": [
                              "lowercase"
                          ],
                          "tokenizer": "keyword"
                      }
                  }
              },
              "number_of_replicas": "0",
              "uuid": "26xckWaOQuuxFrMvIdikvw",
              "version": {
                  "created": "6020199"
              }
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been able to return a non-zero sort value by reproducing your case as shown below:

```
# 1. create the index mapping
PUT sorts
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "some_deep_count": {
        "type": "object"
      }
    }
  }
}

# 2. index a sample document
PUT sorts/_doc/1
{
  "some_deep_count": {
    "0": {
      "29": 1077,
      "32026": 344,
      "55531": 1081,
      "55625": 458
    },
    "1": {
      "29": 88,
      "32026": 57,
      "55625": 60
    }
  }
}

# 3. Sort the results
POST sorts/_search
{
  "sort": {
    "_script": {
      "type": "number",
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "source": """
          def deep0 = 0; 
          def deep1 = 0; 
          if(doc.containsKey('some_deep_count.0.55531')) { 
            deep0 = doc['some_deep_count.0.55531'].value;
          } 
          if(doc.containsKey('some_deep_count.1.55531')) { 
            deep1 = doc['some_deep_count.1.55531'].value;
          } 
          return deep0 + deep1;
        """
      },
      "order": "desc"
    }
  }
}
```

Results => sort = 1081

```
"hits" : [
  {
    "_index" : "sorts",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "1",
    "_score" : null,
    "_source" : {
      "some_deep_count" : {
        "0" : {
          "29" : 1077,
          "32026" : 344,
          "55531" : 1081,
          "55625" : 458
        },
        "1" : {
          "29" : 88,
          "32026" : 57,
          "55625" : 60
        }
      }
    },
    "sort" : [
      1081.0
    ]
  }
]
```

As you can see I'm using `55531` which exists in `some_deep_count.0` but not in `some_deep_count.1` and the result is 1081, which is correct.

Using `*.29` which is available in both 0 and 1 would yield `1165` which is also correct (1077 + 88).

The only difference between my script and yours is that when assigning `deep0` and `deep1` you need to add `.value` to the doc field reference.

**UPDATE**

The problem lies in the fact that you're specifying `dynamic: false` in your mapping. Using that parameter means that if you index new fields that weren't present in your mapping at index creation time, your mapping won't be updated. So as it stands, all the sub-fields that you index in `some_deep_count` are never indexed, which is why you're always getting 0. Remove `dynamic: false` and everything will work as expected.

Comment: Thanks Val. The exact same query here returns `"sort":[0.0]` for all the records. Would you be able to tell me your elasticsearch version?

Comment: Sure, I tested on 7.5 and 6.7.2 and both return 1081. If you get sort = 0, then it means the document doesn't have any of the two fields you're referencing in your script or the cancel out each other (e.g. -10 and +10). Can you show your full request and response, please?

Comment: thanks @Val , I updated the question accordingly, simplifying the things a little bit as well

Comment: It's funny, I've indexed your sample document and executed your exact query and I get 228... Can you show what you get when running `curl -XGET localhost:9200/foos`?

Comment: thanks @Val, I updated the question again. What I will do now, since you've got different results from mine, will be to create a fresh index and insert only some example data in that. Then totally rebuild my current index and check again. It must be an index configuration problem, though, because in my production server I have the same results as in local

Comment: after following your suggestion (`dynamic: true`), the sorting works, the bounty is yours!. now.. because the `some_deep_count`  can potentially have MANY values, I would really like to stay with `dynamic: false`. Would you be able to suggest an alternative strategy?

Comment: Are you afraid of mapping explosion or crossing the default limit of 1000 fields per index?

Comment: both. the keys in the mapping for that object would be in the scale of 100k

Comment: Wow that's huge... but without knowing too much about your use case, it's hard to advise anything.

Comment: I'm trying to explore the possibility of transforming that field in something a bit flatter, that can be mapped differently (or even with a different field datatype)